# how to combine one scrollbar to multiple rich text boxes

Tags: c#

I have a form with several rich text boxes that will generate related information to each other.  They will generate it such that a scrollbar will be automatic for each box.  What I want to do is to have just one scrollbar control all of the boxes or more than one of the boxes at once such that it scrolls several boxes evenly.

I hope I'm making sense.

[form to randomly generate hourly weather for 10 days](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T5lVQ.png)

Found the Panel container.  Thank you.

Comment: One way to solve would be to place all boxes in a long scrollable containter and put a scrollbar on the containter. However, since the information is related maybe you would show it in a related manner? Do you have a collection of your data or something?

Comment: You could also capture the scroll event for each box, and set the remaining scroll offset values to the same.

Comment: there is no collection of data as I am trying to get a random generation during runtime.

Comment: Put the textboxes into a panel so the panel will have scroll bar and each text box will also have a scroll bar.